# Electron app - Custom components in native header

Tags: electron

Is it possible in Electron to put custom components into the native application header?

For example, to achieve a design as such:

[image]

Currently my app just has the default one with just the title text

[image]

Is there a way to make it bigger and put content in there? Or do I have to somehow hide the native header and recreate the native buttons myself?

I suspect it's the latter, but in that case, how do I hide the native one and hook up ability to drag the window with it?

Or is this design entirely not possible in Electron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design you're looking for can be achieved, but only on macOS, by using the `titleBarStyle` property set to either `hidden`, `hiddenInset`, or even `customButtonsOnHover`, in the options passed to [new BrowserWindow()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions).

This is explained in more detail in [Alternatives on macOS](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#alternatives-on-macos):

> There's an alternative way to specify a chromeless window. Instead of
> setting `frame` to `false` which disables both the titlebar and window
> controls, you may want to have the title bar hidden and your content
> extend to the full window size, yet still preserve the window controls
> ("traffic lights") for standard window actions.

There might still be a few issues, such as not being able to drag around the window from its title bar any more, but they are documented in the [Frameless Window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#draggable-region) page; for instance, this specific problem can be solved by adding `-webkit-app-region: drag;` to the CSS relative to the region(s) you wish to make draggable.